# How to convert ByteString into a protobuf Message

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have a message `hMessage` (type of `HMessage`) where I convert it into a `ByteString` using `hMessage.toByteString()`. But in a another point I need to convert this `ByteString` into original `hMessage` (type of `HMessage`). Is there a way to do this without using any IoSession involvements or reading byte streams.

Answer (score 3):

```
HMessage output = HMessage.parseFrom(hMessage.toByteString());
```

So the each protobuf message has its own parse method associated with them.